# Can't enable hardware assisted virtualization in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bios, uefi, hardware-virtualization, android-studio

Virtualization is supported in my PC. Here's the proof:(screenshot of Piriform speccy):

[image: click for my CPU info image]

Please help me in enabling AMD SVM. I have tried many different ways I found on internet which uses uefi firmeware settings. But that is missing in my pc. I have already enabled virtualization in BIOS.
Please help me. I want to use it in android studio as emulation requires hardware virtualization.

Thanks.

Comment: Something else may have taken exclusive control. You say you have Bluestacks installed. Remove it. Also check whether Hyper-V is enabled.

Comment: hyper-v is disabled. I'll try uninstalling bluestacks. But even if bluestacks is taking exclusive control, it means its enabled, then why is it showing disabled in the snip above?

Comment: Because it appears disabled to all other potential users. Its existence can probably still be detected (using the CPUID command), producing the result you got.

Comment: Thanks a lot..... due to some reasons, I cannot remove Bluestacks. But I found that Android Studio can emulate in Bluestacks, which solved my main problem. And it is confirmed that Bluestacks is using acceleration because a message that appeared before enabling it "Your PC supports Virtualization, Learn how to enable" is not shown now. Anyways, Your comment added to my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent bluestacks from taking exclusive control of hardware acceleration? So that it is available to other softwares. Any registry entries that can be changed or some other trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where virtualization feature can be enabled/disabled - it is BIOS.
Try to reset BIOS to default and then enable virtualization again. Sometime CMOS area of BIOS can be corrupted even it show Ok on the BIOS screen.

Try to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and setup any light weight guest Operation system and set there virtualization features (VT-x/AMD-V, nested paging). If VirtualBox wouldn't complain about absence of virtualization features then it something with android studio

Comment: Actually, instead of VirtualBox, I installed bluestacks. Before enabling Virtualization in the BIOS, Bluestaks showed a message that "Your PC supports Virtualization, Learn how to enable(Which showed how to enable it in BIOS)". After I enabled it, that message disappeared. Also the speed of bluestacks increased. So is it something with the android studio? If so the why Virtualization is shown supported but disabled in that speccy image of CPU information? However, I have not tried to set BIOS to default yet, i'll see if that helps. Thank you